# How can I set margins of overlay?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, overlay

I am using a background image and an overlay in my div. But the overlay doesn't overlap properly. It is leaving some margins at both the sides for reasons. I tried setting margins so that it overlaps completely but then it disturbs my layout.
How can i correct it?

```css
/*numscroller*/
.image{
 height:auto;
 width:100%;
 background:#FFCC99;
 }
.over2{
 height:auto;
 width:100%;
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);
 }
 .num{
  margin:auto;
  padding:6rem 0rem;
  float:left;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tinywall/numscroller/master/numscroller-1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row " >
     <div class="col-12 image">
        
         <div class="over2">
                <div class="row justify-content-around">
                    <div class=" num col-10 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                        <center>
                          
                            <h3><b>Slums covered</b></h3>
                            <h3 class='numscroller' data-min='1' data-max='7' data-delay='1' data-increment='1'><b>7</b></h3>
                        </center>
                    </div><!--num col-10 ends-->
                    <div class="num col-10 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 ">
                        <center>
                            
                            <h3><b>Lives changed</b></h3>
                            <h3 class='numscroller' data-min='1' data-max='400' data-delay='1' data-increment='3'><b>400</b></h3>
                        </center>
                    </div><!--num col-10 ends-->
                    <div class="num col-10 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 ">
                        <center>
                            
                            <h3><b>Our supporters</b></h3>
                            <h3 class='numscroller' data-min='1' data-max='30' data-delay='1' data-increment='1'><b>30</b></h3>
                        </center>
                    </div><!--num col-10 ends-->
                </div><!--row justify ends-->
            </div><!--over ends-->
            
        </div><!--col-12 ends-->
    </div><!--row ends-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can position the image container relatively, and the overlay should be position absolutely.

```css
.image {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
    <span>I am the image </span>
    <div class="overlay">
      I am the overlay
    </div>
  </div>
```